# Npgsql / Entity Framework does not alter/create columns in new MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, npgsql

I created a new MVC project in Visual Studio 2013 and added a "CompanyName" field to IdentityModels.cs and AccountViewModels.cs. Then, I installed the latest Npgsql beta with Nuget (`Npgsql 2.1.3` and `Npgsql.EntityFramework 2.1.3`) Next, I opened web.config and set the following connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=DBNAME;User Id=MYUSER;Password=MYPASS;" providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Lastly, I created a new database and renamed the "public" schema in the db to "dbo" with pgadmin. I created a new user role and made it the owner of the "dbo" schema. I created the relevant tables on the schema with [this](http://pastebin.com/eQmCpSFF) SQL script.

However, when I try to register, I get the following error:

```
Exception Details: Npgsql.NpgsqlException: ERROR: 42703: column Extent1.CompanyName does not exist
```

What is that Extent1 table? I thought that the framework will automatically alter tables to add new columns. Is there more setup that needs to be done?

## Update

I added the CompanyName column manually to the AspNetUsers table, and now it gives this error message:
    ERROR: 42703: column Extent1.Discriminator does not exist

Wasn't the Discriminator column removed in later versions of EF? I have EF 6.

## Solution

For anyone else having a similar problem, here is what I did. To the AspNetUsers table, you need to add not only your custom fields, but every table must also have a column named "Discriminator" (case-sensitive) of type "character varying" and length 256. Moreover, check that your individual tables have access to your db user (in my case, the db user was the owner of both the database and the schema, but not the tables within the schema!)

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use an sql generator for Postgres like this:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework.v5.PostgreSql
```

and configure EF to use manual migration?